# Customized Templates

Tags: cognito-forms

I wonder if there is a place where I can find examples of templates done by users or the Cognito team?

I would like to customize a template through the word program but I it seems difficult and to see to build template myself.

My template is meant to summarize what the customer has chosen in the form on the website.

Answer (score 2):

this should be what you're looking for, but if you're looking for more specialized forms, I'm not so sure where to go:  https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates